# How to keep the state of a PageView that is used inside ScreenTypeLayout? (Flutter Web)

Tags: flutter, responsive, flutter-web, state-management

I am using a package called responsive_builder to create a web responsive UI.

My issue is that this package rebuilds the widget that corresponds to the constraints after changing window size.

This causes the loss of user data if inserted in a TextField for example.  Also this causes PageView to lose its state meaning losing the current page index if the page was change earlier before adjusting window size.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a very similar issue happen with a closing/opening container with a Textfield.

You need to use [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to store that data into the memory. [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) effectively keeps that typed data in a map - which is stored in memory and can be used anytime.

Also I highly recommend using [Flutter Form Builder](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder) for your text fields as it allows you to have a initialValue in your TextField and has built in Validation.

Because there is no code to go off, your Textfield should look something like:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 String firstName = '';

_persistantText(String value) async {
    firstName = await prefs.setString(value);
}

 FormBuilderTextField(
            attribute: "firstName",
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "First Name"),
            validators: [
              FormBuilderValidators.required(),
              FormBuilderValidators.max(70),
            ],
            initialValue: firstName
            onChanged: (value){
                _persistantText(value);
            }
          ),
```

Comment: Yes this could be a solution.  I think considering an rx SharedPref so the UI would listen to the changes of this value.  And I would like to ask if it is good to check your answer since their might be other more parctical solution.